# Depending on maven dependency scope compiled or provided produces Ambiguous Bean or ClassNotfoundException

Tags: maven, module, scope, dependencies, classnotfoundexception

Environment:

- Java 11
- JBoss 7.2
- Maven 3.5

I have a project with many maven modules and a common for all. Depend on the scope of dependency compile or provided I am getting *WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous* or *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException*.

How to solve these two errors to once?

When pom.xml (app-back) has dependency app-commons

- When app-commons is scope provided

  **ERROR** java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException
- When app-commons is scope compiled

  **ERROR** WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name version resolves to beans: [Managed Bean [class es.caib.app.commons.utils.Version] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named], Managed Bean [class es.caib.app.commons.utils.Version] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named]]"}}

Modules:

- app (pom)
- app-ear
- app-back (dependency to app-commons)
- app-front (dependency to app-commons)
- app-commons (jasperreport dependency)
- ...

**app-commons** have ReportManager.java that needs jasper dependency and Version.java of type @ApplicationScope

**pom.xml** app-commons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>es.caib.accfor</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>app-commons</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>app-commons</name>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
```

**Version.java** (app-commons)

```
...
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Version {

    private String version;
    private String buildTime;
    private String scmRevision;
    private String jdkVersion;
    private String projectName;
...
```

**ReportManager.java** (app-commons)

```
public class ReportManager {

...
    public static void addParam(Map<String, Object> params, String nom, byte[] compiledReport) throws ReportException {
        try {
            params.put(nom, SerializationUtils.deserialize(compiledReport));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ReportException("Error deserialize compiledReport.");
        }
    }
...
```

In **app-back** module I call ReportManager.addParam()

**SessionScoped.java** (app-back)

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Version version;
...
```

**StartupListener.java** (app-back)

```
@WebListener
public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartupListener.class);

    @Inject
    private Version version;
...
```

Comment: `provided` in pom.xml means that you provided your jar in server lib in your case in jboss lib. Please post your jasper maven dependency in your pom.xml

Comment: Second part `compile` in maven is that you have propably somewhere in your context bean named `Version`. Try to change this bean name `@Named('CustomVersion')` and accordingly start using that qualifer in your application

Comment: The problem is that when is compiled scoped I have no problem with jasperreport exception that throws ReportManager but an applicationScope is ambiguous. Otherwise with provided scoped I have jasperreportException because ClassNotFoundException because that class is not in submodule with dependency app-commons. Can not find a smart way to solve it.

Comment: How can it be that it is the same class of both resolutions? > Name Version resolves to beans: [Managed Bean [class es.caib.accfor.commons.utils.Version] with qualifiers [Default Any Named], Managed Bean [class es.caib.accfor.commons.utils.Version] with qualifiers [Default Any Named]]

Comment: @PawełGłowacz added jasper maven dependency

Comment: Your class `Version` in app-commons is the only class that is `Scoped` ?

Comment: Version in app-commons is the only class in the project with that name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230074/discussion-between-pawel-glowacz-and-joe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of transitive dependencies are not included when dependency is provided, so I had to restructure the modules this way.

Modules:

- app (pom)
- app-ear

  - jasperreports (compiled) MOVED FROM APP-COMMONS
- app-back

  - app-commons (provided)
- app-front

  - app-commons (provided)
- app-commons
  ...

I was not able to change app-commons dependency to compiled because it is dependent of app-front and app-back. In app-commons as compiled I have an @ApplicationScope class that it would produce ambiguous Beans pointing to the class in app-commons because of jakartaee context management.